# Windows 7 64-bit machine won't shutdown after installing and uninstalling WAIK to create WinPE disc

Tags: windows-7, windows-pe

I can shut it down by not logging in which suggests a profile issue, but I'm wondering if there is a known issue. -TIA

Comment: WinPE is an operating system, not software you can install on Win7.

Comment: Sorry WAIK to create a WinPE disc